# While loop Python displaying values less a certain value

Tags: arrays, python-3.x

I'm trying to display values in array that is `z[i]^4` and less than `100000` and then display the number of elements that meet the less than 100000, but I get index 100 is out of bounds for axis 0 with size 100.

I'm not sure what to do. Forgive my horrible wording.

```
import numpy as np

z = np.array(range(100))
k = 0
while k <= 100:
    k = k+1
    z[k]=k**4
    print(z) 
a = sum(i <= 30 for i in z)
print(a)
```

Comment: `z1 = sum(i < 100000 for i in z)` <- that is a syntax error. Do you mean to use a list comprehension?

Comment: I don't get why you are using `k < 277` . The while loop will not work when `k = 101` because `z` only has 100 items.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If what you want is z to have values of `i^4` up to `100000` you can do this:

```
import numpy as np

z = np.array(range(100))
k = 0
while k < len(z) - 1:
    k = k+1
    if k**4 >= 100000:
        break
    else:
        z[k]=k**4
    print(z)
```

I'm not sure this is the most efficient way to compute this, but I kept a similar syntax of yours so it's easier for you to understand the changes. The way I'd do:

```
import numpy as np

z = np.array(range(100))

for number in z:
    if number**4 <= 100000:
        z[number]=number**4
        print(number**4)
    else:
        break
```

This, besides editing the list values, also achieves your requirement of "display values for which `i^4` is less than `100000`".

Pythonic solution using list comprehension:

```
z = range(100)
>>> [x**4 for x in z if x**4 <= 100000]
[0, 1, 16, 81, 256, 625, 1296, 2401, 4096, 6561, 10000, 14641, 20736, 28561, 38416, 50625, 65536, 83521]
```

Answer (score 0):

I think that you misunderstand that the maximal index into a numpy array (and also a list and a tuple) is one less the numpy array (list and tuple length) size. By the way: `range(100)` creates values from 0 to 99 not from 1 to 100 ...

Try this code:

```
import numpy as np

z = np.array(range(100))

print(z[0])
print(z[99])
print(z[100])
```

which gives:

```
0
99
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "numpyIndex_Cg.py", line 7, in <module>
    print(z[100])
IndexError: index 100 is out of bounds for axis 0 with size 100
```

to see yourself what I am talking about.